# Getting certain columns in bash

Tags: bash

Suppose I have an array where each element in the array is in the following format:

```
someText (x1,y1,z1) (x2,y2,z2) (x3,y2,z3) KEY
```

What is the approach for building a new array where is element in the new array is only 1st and last column of the previous array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this (where `OLDARRAY` is the previous array and `NEWARRAY` is the new one).

```
NEWARRAY=()
for I in "${!OLDARRAY[@]}"; do
    IFS=$' ' read -ra T <<< "${OLDARRAY[I]}"
    NEWARRAY[I]="${T[0]} ${T[@]:(-1)}"
done
```

Example output:

```
> set | grep ^NEWARRAY
NEWARRAY=([0]="someText KEY" [1]="someText2 KEY2")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get first and last element of your string in the array:

```
echo "someText (x1,y1,z1) (x2,y2,z2) (x3,y2,z3) KEY" | rev | cut -d " " -f 1 | rev

echo "someText (x1,y1,z1) (x2,y2,z2) (x3,y2,z3) KEY" | cut -d " " -f 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "someText (x1,y1,z1) (x2,y2,z2) (x3,y2,z3) KEY"|awk '{print $1,$NF}'
```

Comment: This fails to assign anything to a new array.  See @konsolebox' answer instead.