# Getting columns and inserting into array [Bash]

Tags: bash

I have an array in which every element is in the following format:

```
somePlane (1,2,3) (1,0,0) (0,0,1) R
```

I want to create a new new array from it using only 1st and last column with the following command:

```
newArr=( "echo ${arr[*]}" | awk '{print $1,$5}` )
```

Above command doesn't works as I expecting, what am I missing?

Comment: What do you expect it to print? `somePlane R`?

Comment: Is it just a typo or even in the code you have ` at the end of the awk command? The right syntax is just with the single quote: `awk '{print $1,$5}' `

Comment: Yes. I expect "somePlane R" to go into an array cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I gave you in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591688/getting-certain-columns-bash) was already the answer you needed.

```
NEWARRAY=()
for I in "${!OLDARRAY[@]}"; do
    IFS=$' ' read -ra T <<< "${OLDARRAY[I]}"
    NEWARRAY[I]="${T[0]} ${T[@]:(-1)}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you this indeed works, but I would like to know why what I tired didn't work. [Gave you an upvote]

Comment: @Doppelganger The proper syntax for your command inside is `IFS=$'\n'; newArr=($(echo "${arr[*]}" | awk '{print $1,$5}'))`. The only problem with that command is that (a) You have to change your IFS variable to $'\n', globally. (b) If any of the values you have becomes a valid pattern, it would expand with pathname expansion. So you have to disable pathname expansion or use another format tool like `readarray`.

Comment: @Doppelganger If I am going to use that kind of command I'd do it this way: `readarray -t newArray < <(IFS=$'\n'; echo "${arr[*]}" | awk '{print $1,$5}')`. Only thing is that most of the time it's actually better if you're not calling other external binaries like awk.